# ArcGIS Server 10.1 - GPU Processing Support

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, gpgpu

Does ArcGIS Server 10.1 or any of its extensions (e.g. 3D Analyst, Spatial Analyst) take advantage of GPU processing?

Dell have a new server, the R820, that has an option to include a GPU. Hence the interest.

Comment: There is an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000086rQ) requesting [Manifold-like](http://www.georeference.org/doc/nvidia_cuda.htm) [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU) capabilities that is "under consideration". However, I would be surprised to hear if there is anything like this planned for the next version of ArcGIS, especially on the server side.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath, given how long it's taken ESRI to take advantage of such basic things as 64-bit processors.

Comment: I know that there was some talk of them experimenting with CUDA, but this was more for consuming 3D resources, and for the clients to have the Graphics Cards.

Answer (score 2):

Server doesn't take advantage of GPU processing, nor do the extensions you mention. [System requirements](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/arcgis-for-server-system-requirements.htm) for Server don't mention GPUs at all.